# Using two openvpn clients to expose services of a server

Tags: firewall, openvpn, gateway, tunnel

I am currently attempting to use two openvpn clients to expose services of a server, as is already said in the title. I may be playing with powers far beyond my current comprehension, but please bear with me :-)

### Outline

This is my current setup:

```
           INTERNET eth0 |          | VPN tun0

                  /----- perimeter-a -----\ 
internet clients-:                         :------ server
                  \----- perimeter-b -----/
```

`server` is also the VPN-Server in this case. `perimeter-a` and `perimeter-b` are VPN-Clients.

`server` has eth0 (public interface), eth1 (another public interface) and tun0 (vpn interface).
Each `perimeter` has eth0 (public interface) and tun0 (vpn interface).

### The Goal

The goal is for any `internet client` to be able to speak with either `perimeter-a` or `perimeter-b` and have it look like they are being served by either of those while, in fact, you are being served by `server`. Connecting to a game server (for example) on `perimeter-a` and connecting to a game server on `perimeter-b` will make you end up at `server` everytime.

The only exception to this rule should be when `perimeter-a` or `perimeter-b` does not forward a corresponding port. Ports should be forwarded explicitly on either of those two machines. UDP and TCP should both be handled.

### Previous Attempts

My previous attempt depended on NAT via iptables but had the problem of losing the address of the actual `internet client` on `server`. The address of the `internet client` should be preserved - which is why I have then decided to use a VPN and primarily drive traffic from and to `server` through that.

### Idea and current attempt

My current attempt is using `perimeter-a` and `perimeter-b` as internet gateways for `server`. The problem is, that I am not sure about whether or not it is possible to set this up when both `perimeters` are VPN clients instead of servers.

Can I pass a packet from any of the `perimeters` to `server` without rewriting the packet source and then send it back to any of the `perimeters` by figuring out that it came in on `server` via tun0? But then I'd need to have two tun-interfaces to differ between both `perimeters`, right? And then, when those packets arrive on `perimeter-XY`, I'd need to have that machine rewrite the source to itself and send it to the `internet client`, given that the packet came from tun0 - correct?

I'm completely lost at this point and I couldn't find anything describing my actual case. How far am I away from the solution? Am I going about it the wrong way? Is all this even possible?

In essence I am trying to build two pseudo-gateways and one machine to use them depending on where a connection came from.

**Edit 1**: The three servers in question are not on the same LAN - They are located in entirely different locations each.

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly what you're trying to achieve is addressed by the Linux Virtual Server project -  http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/ (but I might well be missing something).

Comment: After reading the project page for a bit this really seems like what i am looking for :) I'd gladly accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly what you're trying to achieve is addressed by the Linux Virtual Server project - http://linuxvirtualserver.org/. At the very least it will give you pointers to the issues.